# Show/Hide issue with 2 select menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I select 'US', I want my `statecat` dropdown to appear. Why isn't it currently doing this?

Many thanks for any help.

http://jsfiddle.net/3esurLwt/

*HTML*

```
<select name="cat" id="cat">
    <option value="uk">uk</option>
    <option value="us">us</option>
</select>

<select name="statecat" id="statecat">
    <option value="me">maine</option>
    <option value="ge">georgia</option>
</select>
```

*Javascript*

```
jQuery('#cat').change(function(){
if(jQuery('#cat').val()=="us")
    jQuery('form#stateSwitch').show();
else {
    jQuery('form#stateSwitch').hide();
})

if(jQuery('#cat').val()=="0")
jQuery('form#languageSwitch').siblings('div').show();
    else{
    jQuery('form').siblings('div').hide();
    jQuery('.'+jQuery('#cat').val()).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: You have one closing paranthesis too much in line 6 of your javascript (at least when the second if/else statement is to be considered a part of your handler function, otherwise you are missing a curly bracket in line 6 and the last line is obsolete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple use toggle:

```js
jQuery('#cat').change(function() {
  $("#statecat").toggle($(this).val() == "us");
});
```

```css
#statecat {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cat" id="cat">
  <option value="uk">uk</option>
  <option value="us">us</option>
</select>
<select name="statecat" id="statecat">
  <option value="me">maine</option>
  <option value="ge">georgia</option>
</select>
```

**Reference**

[**.toggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)